# remove duplicated letters from string (arabic)

Tags: php, duplicates, arabic

i want to delete all duplicated letters in this string:
`سسسللام علييكمم`

and make it like this:
`سلام عليكم`

i try this:

```
$str = "hhhii brroo iiiimmm aaaaallllliiii";
echo shell_exec("echo " . $str . " | tr -s 'a-z'");
```

but its only works in English words

Answer (score 1):

To use shell to remove duplicated characters is too hardcore I guess.

I tried to write a code:

```
<?php
$string = "سسسللام علييكمم";
$ret = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string);$i++){
    if (strpos($ret, $string[$i]) === false) {
        $ret .= $string[$i];
    }
}

echo $ret;
```

Sadly it's doesn't work on the end characters.